# Decomposing the universal enveloping algebra into a direct sum of irreducibles

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

In the case of $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{su}_2$ (the Lie algebra of $SU(2)$), the universal enveloping algebra can be decomposed into irreducibles as
$$
U(\mathfrak{g}) = \bigoplus_{j=0}^\infty V_{2j+1},
$$
where $V_d$ is an irreducible representation of $SU(2)$ of dimension $d$ (e.g., see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209988/do-representations-of-the-universal-enveloping-algebra-mathrmu-mathfraksu)).

Can we make a similar statement for $SU(n)$ in general? That is, which irreducibles does $U(\mathfrak{g})$ decompose into (and with what multiplicity) when $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{su}_n$?

I would guess there is some explicit map/algorithm to compute this? For example, when $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{su}_2$ then
\begin{align*}
\mathfrak{g}^{\otimes 0} &= V_1 \\
\mathfrak{g}^{\otimes 1} &= V_3 \\
\mathfrak{g}^{\otimes 2} &= V_1 \oplus V_3 \oplus V_5 \\
\mathfrak{g}^{\otimes 3} &= V_1 \oplus V_3 \oplus V_3 \oplus V_3 \oplus V_5 \oplus V_5 \oplus V_7. \\
\end{align*}
So it seems like $V_{2j+1}$ can be roughly related to $\mathfrak{g}^{\otimes j}$.

Comment: I don't think that decomposition is correct? For example, $U(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ contains $1$ and the Casimir element $ef+fe+\frac12h^2$, which are linearly independent and $\mathfrak g$ acts trivially.

Comment: @KentaS Yeah I have been reading up and I think you're correct (or I am misunderstanding something). The PBW theorem seems to say that the associated graded envelope $\mathrm{gr} U (\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ is canonically isomorphic to the symmetric algebra $\mathrm{Sym}( \mathfrak{sl}_2)$. Then for example, $\mathfrak{g}^{\otimes 2}$ should be related not to $V_5$ but to $V_1 \oplus V_5$ instead which resolves the point you made.

Comment: @KentaS It acts trivially on the Casimir element in terms of the universal algebras action on itself but not necessarily in terms of the action induced from the adjoint action on the tensor algebra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is unclear to me why you compute $\mathfrak{g}^{\otimes j}$. The universal enveloping algebra is a quotient of the tensor algebra, so $T^j(\mathfrak{g}) = \mathfrak{g}^{\otimes j}$ will not share the irreducible decomposition of $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$.

Secondly, the decomposition of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ seems wrong: recall that $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}) \cong \mathcal{S}(\mathfrak{g})$ (the symmetric algebra, which can be interpreted as polynomials in $\mathfrak{g}$) as $\mathfrak{g}$-modules. Then clearly $\mathcal{S}^2(\mathfrak{g})$ has dimension 6, generated by polynomials $e^2, f^2, h^2, eh, fe, fh$. At the same time, $e^2$ is a maximal vector of weight 4, so it generates an irreducible $\mathfrak{g}$-module isomorphic to $V_5$. It follows that the decomposition of $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ is $V_1 \oplus V_5$. But we also have $\mathcal{U}^0(\mathfrak{g}) \cong V_1$ (ie the scalars). Thus we see that $V_1$ appears multiple times in the decomposition, and not just once.

So let's think this through from the start. First of all, what is the decomposition of $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{su}(2)$ as a $\mathfrak{g}$-module into simple modules? Well, we know $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ is simple, and a submodule of the adjoint representation is the same as an ideal. Therefore, the adjoint representation must be simple. For $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, we have simply $\mathfrak{su}(2) \cong V_3$ as $\mathfrak{su}(2)$-modules. Next, we need a way to compute the decomposition of symmetric powers of $V_3$. This sort of problem (with tensor, symmetrix or exterior powers) is called $\textbf{plethysm}$. It is a hard problem in general but many specific cases have been worked out. For the tensor product case, there is Steinberg's formula. The symmetric power case of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ it is not too bad, see for instance [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299900/symmetric-powers-for-lie-algebras) post.

For $\mathfrak{su}(3)$, we can see that $\mathfrak{su}(3) \cong L(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)$. This is the irreducible module with highest weight vector having weight $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2$. Next we would need to find the decomposition of $\mathcal{S}^j(L(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2))$. Unfortunately I didn't find anything that would help with this through a cursory online search.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "Can we make a similar statement for $SU(n)$ in general? That is, which irreducibles does $U(\mathfrak{g})$ decompose into (and with what multiplicity) when $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{su}_n$?"

**Answer:** If $V$  is any irreducible $SU(n)$-module, let $0 \neq v \in V$ be any non zero vector. Since $SU(n)$ is semi simple, the surjective map

$$\phi_v: U(\mathfrak{su}(n)) \rightarrow V$$

defined by $\phi_v(z):=zv$, splits. Hence $U(\mathfrak{su}(n)) \cong W \oplus V$.
Hence any irreducible module $V$ is a direct summand of $U(\mathfrak{su}(n))$.

**Note:** The above argument proves that an irreducible $SU(n)$-module $W$ is either finite dimensional or countably infinite dimensional, since by the PBW theorem it follows $U(\mathfrak{su}(n))$ is countably infinite dimensional.